# How to scan the string and convert dynamically in SAS

Tags: sas, substr

Supposed I have two strings to convert from SAS program name to table number.

My goal is to convert the first "f-2-2-7-5-vcb" to "2.2.7.5". 
And this should be done dynamically. Like for "f-2-2-12-1-2-hbd87q",
it needed to be "2.2.12.1.2" .

How to accomplish this?

```
data input; 
input str $ 1-20; 
datalines;
f-2-3-1-5-vcb
f-2-4-1-6-rtg
f-2-3-11-1-3-hb17
;
run;

data want;
 set input;
 Sub=compress(substr(str,3,length(str)),,'kd') ;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a longer way, but this works fine for me.

- Use FIND() to find the first '-'
- Use REVERSE() and FIND() to find the
  last '-'
- Use SUBSTR() and metrics + math from above to remove the first and
  last components
- Use TRANSLATE() to convert the - to periods.

  ```
   z=find(str, '-');
   end=find(strip(reverse(str)), '-');
   string = translate(substr(str, z+1, length(str) - z - end), ".", "-");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression can match the dash delimited digits only sequence.  The match, when extracted, can be transformed using `translate`.

```
data input; 
input str $ 1-20; 

rx = prxparse ("/^.*?((\d+)(-\d+)*)/");

if prxmatch(rx,str) then do;
  call prxposn (rx,1,s,e);
  name = substr(str,s,e);
  name = translate(name,'.','-');
end;

datalines;
f-2-3-1-5-vcb
f-2-4-1-6-rtg
f-2-3-11-1-3-hb17
funky2-2-1funky
f-2-hb17
a2bfunky
;
run;
```

A funky situation occurs if the digits only token sequence is preceded by a token ending with digits, or succeeded by a token starting with digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
data input; 
input str $ 1-20; 
string=translate(prxchange('s/\w+?\-(.*)\-\w+/$1/',-1,strip(str)),'.','-');
datalines;
f-2-3-1-5-vcb
f-2-4-1-6-rtg
f-2-3-11-1-3-hb17
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line. Use subtr to keep the text between the second word and last word:

**translate(substr(str,find(str,scan(str,2,'-')),find(str,scan(str,-1,'-'))-find(str,scan(str,2,'-'))-1),'.','-')**

1. find(str,scan(str,2,'-') : finds the starting position of the second
   word.
2. find(str,scan(str,-1,'-') : finds the starting position of the last
   word.
3. step2 - find(str,scan(str,2,'-'))-1 : find ending position of second
   last word (length of text to copy).
4. Translate function: replaces '-' with '.'

substr(str,step1,step3) : copy text between second word and second to last.

**Code:**

```
data want;
 set input;
 Sub=translate(substr(str,find(str,scan(str,2,'-')),find(str,scan(str,-1,'-'))-find(str,scan(str,2,'-'))-1),'.','-');
 put _all_;
run;
```

**Output:**

```
str=f-2-3-1-5-vcb Sub=2.3.1.5
str=f-2-4-1-6-rtg Sub=2.4.1.6 
str=f-2-3-11-1-3-hb17 Sub=2.3.11.1.3
```